# Load Large Data Faster using CURL APIs - Make website faster

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm looking for a suggestion on how can I improve my code to load website faster. I don't have database access directly, only APIs are exposed. There is a large set of data coming from APIs and website home page is has 5 carousals for different cities.

Basically, on my home page, I'm using a curl call to read the data from API and then displaying on home page. My code is like below

```
$citiesArr = array(1 => 'Tokyo', 2 => 'Los Angeles', 3 => 'London'); // cities array with their primary key

$foreach ($citiesArr as $city) {
    // City Title Goes here
    // Using curl here by passing city id to API which return large amount of json data.
    handle = curl_init();
    $baseUrl = "API_BASE_PATH/data?city_id=" . $cityId;
    curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_URL, $baseUrl . $path);
    curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $response = curl_exec($handle);
    curl_close($handle);
    $response = json_decode($response, TRUE);
    $results = array_slice($response , 0, 10, true); // There is large data so slicing to get only first 10 posts

    // Displaying the data 
    $foreach ($results as $result) {
       // Displaying data here, There is own carousal on homepage, you just swipe to see all posts
    }

}
```

Images and everything is already optimized, it takes minimum of 20 seconds to load the website. There are other things on home page too, but if i remove my code, the website loads within 2 seconds, but my this code makes website loads too slow.

Issue: When you hit the url in browser, it takes minimum of 7 seconds to hit the website and then loads the website in another 15-20 seconds, which means it more than 25 seconds. if i remove my code, website hits faster, I thought the issue is with DNS, domain etc, but there is no issue with it, The issue is with my code.

Is it possible to load the html first and then hit the curl to load website, but website doesnot look bad, or any other way.

Please note: I can't use ajax because API doesn't provide limited post, it just provide large data, but I only want to display few, If don't use slice for array, it takes forever to load the website, Thats why I'm trying to load my website faster.

A sample view looks like this

[image]

Comment: How often does the data change? Chances are you'll want some server-side process making these calls and storing the responses somewhere, and you'd access *that* cached data instead of a curl call for every request.

Comment: Data from APIs are updated daily , sometimes data is updated in a week for each city, sometimes 10-50 posts are added daily

Comment: I have another page, which has all the data, which is very slow, but atleast, I want to make my home page faster.

Comment: Main issue is, its hitting the website after 6-7 seconds, but once my code is removed, it hits within a sec and loads in 3 seconds.

Comment: If the data changes daily, have a cron that fetches all the data you need once daily, and store it on **your** server. Then access that data directly as-needed.

Answer (score 0):

What you have here is a basic bottleneck problem. Your bottleneck is that each curl request must first wait to be complete before the next curl request may even begin.

Imagine you have 10 bunnies. Each bunny must make a trip down a maze, grab a carrot, and return back to the starting position. On average each bunny needs at least 10 seconds to complete the task. If you only send out one bunny at a time, each bunny must wait until the next bunny returns before they can start down the maze, this task will takes us at least 100 seconds. But if we allow all 10 bunnies to go out at once the task takes only 10 seconds.

So instead of `foreach($reqs as $req) curl_exec(...)` consider using something like [`curl_multi_exec`](http://php.net/curl-multi-exec) which allows you to start all your requests at the same time (*concurrently*).

What this means is that `T = max(t)` in all cases. Where `T` is the total time taken to complete all tasks and `t` represents an array of time taken to complete individual tasks. So the entire time needed is always equal to the maximum amount of time taken by any one individual task (*in all cases*).

This is opposed to your current approach where `T = sum(t)` such that the total time needed to complete all tasks is equal to the sum of individual time taken by each task (*in all cases*).

Comment: I have used multiple curl, but still it takes 6-7 seconds to hit the website, after that it takes less time, but why still 6-7 seconds

Comment: The same way you apply it now. The only thing that changes here is the response are gathered in a separate loop from the loop that sends out the requests. Consider reading the documentation on `curl_multi_*` for examples on how that works.

Comment: Again, apply the formulat `T = max(t)`. Say `t = [0.1, 0.2, 0.1, 0.3, 7]`. So `T = 7`. The sum of time taken is always equal to the worst response time from the collective result. So it only one request being really slow to slow down the whole thing, but this is still far better than your current approach where `T = sum(t)`, i.e. the collective sum of **all** requests. Why specifically one requests or multiple requests take N time is not something I can answer for sure. There are many variables involved. For example, the server may be rate-limiting or throttling your requests.

Comment: The main issue is to hit the website faster, for example if i remove 2 cities from array, it takes 4 seconds to hit. which means each takes 2 seconds to hit the website, data is loaded after that, what if i have 10 cities, it might take 20 seconds to hit the website and then load  the website, which will take more than 40 seconds. Is there any other approach to load website first then hit curl etc

Comment: Consider that many APIs have certain limits in place to prevent abuse by clients. Such as you can only make N requests per Y time. Or you can only make N requests per client in Y time. Once these limits are reached any number of re-precautions may come into play on the server's end. It may, for example, block all other requests until N requests are complete and Y time has elapsed, or it may just return a failure response immediately. That I can't say. This could also just be the server on the other end is slow to response for *unknown* reason(s).

Comment: I'm sorry, *hit the website* and *hit curl* mean the same thing to me in this context. Curl is the thing *hitting the website*. So I'm afraid your question makes no sense to me.

Comment: Yes, i mean the same, website hit faster without curl code, as i have explained above, when i use curl it takes extra seconds to hit the website.

Comment: A ***faster*** approach (than your current approach) is exactly what my answer provides. The idea that you want it to be faster still is an entirely different set of problems that need solved. Problems of optimization, rate-limiting, throttling, caching, latency, etc... I cannot possibly provide an answer to all of those in a single SO question. Sorry.

Comment: Again, your current approach of using curl is inherently slow because you've created a bottleneck. So the proposed solution is an improvement on that. How you improve further from there is a separate question(s) that needs addressing on its own.

Comment: So how can i improve furthur, I have done with multi curl last time, it was better but not much, still website takes 25 seconds to load.